# Capistrano: No servers for .... puma.state stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Currently running capistrano for deployment:

Environment:
`Capistrano 2.15.5`

`RAILS_ENV=uat cap deploy`

```
2013-11-22 04:27:34 executing `puma:stop'
* no servers for "cd /home/ubuntu/fancied-server/current; bundle exec pumactl -S /home/ubuntu/fancied-server/shared/sockets/puma.state stop"
```

My Capistrano:

```
require "capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, :local           # use the same ruby as used locally for deployment
set :rvm_autolibs_flag, "read-only"       # more info: rvm help autolibs

before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_rvm'  # install RVM
before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_ruby' # install Ruby and create gemset, OR:

if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'uat'
  # The address of the remote host on EC2 (the Public DNS address)
  set :location, "54.252.151.190"
  set :branch, "uat"
  role :app, location
  role :web, location
  role :db,  location, :primary => true
  role :resque, location
  role :rapns, location

  #after 'deploy:stop', 'puma:stop'
  #after 'deploy:start', 'puma:start'
  #after 'deploy:restart', 'puma:restart'

  # Ensure the tmp/sockets directory is created by the deploy:setup task and
  # symlinked in by the deploy:update task. This is not handled by Capistrano
  # v2 but is fixed in v3.
  #shared_children.push('tmp/sockets')

  _cset(:puma_cmd) { "#{fetch(:bundle_cmd, 'bundle')} exec puma" }
  _cset(:pumactl_cmd) { "#{fetch(:bundle_cmd, 'bundle')} exec pumactl" }
  _cset(:puma_state) { "#{shared_path}/sockets/puma.state" }
  _cset(:puma_socket) { "unix://#{shared_path}/sockets/puma.sock" }
  _cset(:puma_role) { :app }
end

namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :web, :on_error => :continue do
    if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'uat'
      if !puma.puma_pid_exists?
        puma.start
      else
        puma.restart
      end
    else
      run start_command
    end
    sleep 2
    warmup_cache
  end
....


namespace :puma do
  desc 'Start puma'
  task :start, :roles => lambda { fetch(:puma_role) }, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue, :on_error => :continue do
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{fetch(:puma_cmd)} #{start_options}", :pty => false
  end

  desc 'Stop puma'
  task :stop, :roles => lambda { fetch(:puma_role) }, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue, :on_error => :continue do
    run "cd #{current_path}; #{fetch(:pumactl_cmd)} -S #{state_path} stop"
  end

  desc 'Restart puma'
  task :restart, :roles => lambda { fetch(:puma_role) }, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue, :on_error => :continue do
    run "cd #{current_path}; #{fetch(:pumactl_cmd)} -S #{state_path} restart"
  end
end
```

So the question would be: is the server set correctly? Or how to set the server, so the it will stop bugging about the issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way of testing it right now, but have you tried moving the server location and roles outside the if block.

Before deploying (at least for the first time), its always a good practice to do a cap deploy:check. It will check if basic dependencies are satisfied, like having the right permissions, checking if svn/git is installed etc.

For multistage deployments, Capistrano actually provides a much cleaner way of defining roles, servers and other environment specific configuration by first defining the roles in config/deploy.rb and then having an environment specific configuration file under config/deploy/*.rb (* - environment). 
As an example you could define the stages on config/deploy.rb in this way:

```
set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "staging"
```

And then you could define environment specific configuration, in its own config file. For example, on config/deploy/production.rb:

```
set :rails_env, 'production'

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do
    # ...
  end

  task :stop do
    # ...
  end

  task :restart do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension